# What is this JavaScript hack?

Tags: javascript, frontend

I found this code in a Javascript, and I am wondering if this is a kind of hack, or just a mistake :

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = myHttpSrc;
img.onload = function () {
    img.onload = null;
};
```

Comment: It seems pretty redundant but I'm not sure how we could ever know without any context...

Comment: Well, at the very least, it has a race condition. (Yes, really.) If the image is in cache, the browser may trigger the `load` event as soon a `src` is set, before the next line of code runs. (Because although JavaScript in browsers is single-threaded -- unless you use web workers -- the browser itself *is not*. It can happily trigger the event, see there are no handlers hooked to it, and so not queue them for execution when the JavaScript thread next becomes availble.)

Comment: Some more context : this is in a function binded to the `onclick` event of a link. The function always `return true`.

Answer (score 1):

The code seems to load an image from `myHttpSrc`.  There is an event handler for `onload` which will be triggered when it is loaded.  The handler is also removing itself once the load is completed.

This is not a hack, but as the `onload` handler is not doing anything other than removing itself it seems redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand a little on Kami's answer, a possible scenario where this could be necessary is that perhaps somewhere else in the code they check to see if img.onload is null or not - perhaps as a way of checking whether or not the image has loaded without using a boolean.

It sounds far from ideal to me and a little outlandish, but hey, it's possible.

And that's my point: no one can know whether or not this was a hack or a mistake without the context in which this code has been given.

If you **need** to know the answer: *ask the person who wrote the code.*